# Filter out one square wave while retaining the other

Tags: high-pass-filter, square

I have two square wave signals. The first signal has a frequency around 10 kHz, while the other signal has a higher frequency of about 50 kHz. How can I filter out the lower frequency signal without affecting the higher frequency signal too much? I simulated using high-pass a filter, but it strongly influenced the higher frequency signal.

Comment: Quite obvious XY-question. You ask filtering because you have somehow decided it solves your actual problem. It probably doesn't because 10kHz square wave has plenty of stuff much above 10kHz and nobody here knows how much it's allowed or how much that 50kHz signal is allowed to get changed. Someone may suggest something actually useful if you bother to reveal the actual problem.

Comment: Please post a schematic of the high pass filter that did not work well.

Comment: Not an XY question. Filtering implies the separation of two signals, not necessarily sinusoidal.The question isasking how to filter out one square wave from a composite of two square waves.

Comment: if you know something about these square waves, frequency ranges, amplitudes, then you might be able to create a logic circuit that outputs a 50 kHz square wave in response to a 50 kHz input, but not to a 10 kHz input, but it wouldn't be a linear filter. Square waves are not sine waves, filters don't play nice with them

Comment: What you think of as "filter" will probably not take you very far here, Yson. This cake for techniques usually found in *clock recovery*, not *filtering*. However, because you don't tell us what you want to do with these signals, and in fact, how they actually look like, it's very hard to advise you specifically.

Comment: Have you considered a PLL (Phase Locked Loop) IC and/or circuit?

Answer (score 0):

You need a high-pass filter or a notch filter, for example, but it's very difficult because these frequencies are so close together.

There are only 2.32 octaves between 10kHz and 50kHz.

Knowing that the order of the filter is equal to : "Order × 6dB" per octave, with linear attenuation (in the dB scale).

For example, a 3rd-order filter has an attenuation of 18dB per octave. With a spacing of 2.32 octaves, the delta of attenuation is 42dB between your frequencies. If you don't want to attenuate 50 kHz, you can only attenuate 10 kHz by 42 dB.

So you need a very very high-order filter or i suggest you use a digital filter.

Answer (score 0):

Square waves are the [sum of odd harmonics](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ihiapwpgw) of a sine wave of a base frequency, The components are *f* (fundamental) with amplitude *a* + 1/3 the amplitude of the third harmonic, + 1/5 the amplitude of the fifth harmonic...

For that reason, you'd need narrow notch **filters** for the fundamental and all undesired harmonics of the frequency to block. Not a simple task!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two signals whose frequency profiles overlap each other.
A square wave is made up of the odd harmonics of the fundamental so a 10 kHz square wave will have significant energy at 30 kHz, 50 kHz, 70 kHz, 90 kHz, etc..

An FFT of the two square waves shows how they overlap. Of course this is dependent on the exact frequencies (you said ***around*** 10 kHz and ***about*** 50 kHz) and their amplitudes. Their relative phase may also play a role in how difficult they are to separate.

[image]

A 50 kHz square wave will consist of frequencies that are all odd harmonics of 10 kHz, so a high pass or notch filters would have to attenuate the 50 kHz signal to filter out any part of the 10 kHz signal above the 3rd harmonic. Even if you had an ideal filter that cut everything below 50 kHz you'd still have parts of the 10 kHz signal getting through. You might be able to use a DSP to separate the signals or maybe a PLL could lock on to the 50 kHz.